# PHP MySQL return special characters

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make this query also return special characters/danish letters (å, æ, ø)?

```
$sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM artists WHERE formated_name LIKE '".$letter."%'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$data = $query->result();
```

I read something about `regex` or `str_replace`?

right now it returns `%C3%A6` - when it comes to these letters...

thanks in advance...

Comment: it could depends of the encoding of your DB. Are you using ASCII? UTF8? Other encoding?

Comment: I use `utf8 without bom` but I also tried `utf8` and there is no difference...

Comment: for the HTML content, or for the dataBase?

Answer (score 1):

`%C3%A6` is [percent encoded data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

You can decode it with [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

It is an odd choice of format for data stored in a database, so you should probably look into fixing whatever adds the data to the database so that it stores the actual characters instead of the percent encoded versions of them.

Comment: ah ok! how do I implement `urldecode` into my example?

Comment: `$someString = urldecode($someStringFromTheDatabase);`